# Rotate label - Material UI button

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I've got a button like this (material-ui):

```js
//theme.js
export const XButtonTop = withStyles({
  root: {
    borderColor: medium_col,
    borderRadius: 1,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 16,
    borderTopRightRadius: 16,
    height: 28
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontSize: "10px"
  }
})(Button);
```

```js
//App.js
import {
  XButtonTop
} from "../theme";

const Selector = state => {
return (
<div>
  <XButtonTop fullWidth size="small" disableElevation>
  )
  </XButtonTop>
</div>
)
}
```

**I need to rotate the label (90 degrees).**

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
    transform: 'rotate(-90deg)',
  }
```

Then you may want to change the height of the button too. Something like this for the root:

```
height: 120,
width: 30
```